# update object created in another datacontext

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I need your help very much. I'd like to update object created in another datacontext;
Here is my code. Insert statement works well but I can't write code for update

```
var dataContext = new ReconNewDataContext();           
        if (Id == 0)
        {
            var item = this;
            dataContext.RequestIO.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            Id = item.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            var item = this;
            //update object
        }
```

I've read 
[Linq2SQL: Update object not created in datacontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371439/linq2sql-update-object-not-created-in-datacontext)

I've tried to use .Attach(this) .Attach(this,true) .Attach(this, oldObjectFromBase) but always I've an errors.

I know I can get object from database and manually transfer data from modified object, but there will be new fields. It means that I must always append these new fields in Save() method.

Is there any "beautiful" method to update object created in another datacontext?

Comment: I just posted a similar question because I've seen this question asked at least 20 times and there is not single "correct" answer. No "beautiful" method that I've found yet. It's making we a) start to go a little insane and b) start to question the wisdom of using Linq To Sql in my repository. Is EF any better at updating disconnected data? Is there a better approach I can use in my repositories?

I wish I had an answer for you but I'm still looking for one myself. :(

Comment: I ask myself the same question... Nhibernate would have made my life easier...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: http://omaralzabir.com/linq_to_sql__how_to_attach_object_to_a_different_data_context/

Also, in your example, for update, try doing:

```
var item = new ObjectBeingUpdated();
//copy over properties from old object to new object, make sure pk's match

//Attach this new object
```

Something similar worked for my coworker I believe.

UPDATE: Check this out for more info about attach: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/10/08/attach-if-you-have-something-detached.aspx

Comment: //copy over properties from old object to new object, make sure pk's match

As I said before it will work but it is not "beatiful" way. How about 42 fields in table? Sure I can use system.reflection. But is there any "beautiful" method to update object created in another datacontext?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern:

1. Fetch existing object from repository
2. Use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to copy properties
3. Save your object back.

Comment: This is what i did... However when saving xelements or any data that is mapped to an xml field you will find that this does not work...